# Typescript return empty object type syntax

Tags: typescript, ecmascript-6

What is the meaning of '{}' in the return function, how that typescript syntax could be interpreted to es7.

```
export const genericRetryStrategy = ({
  maxRetryAttempts = 3,
  scalingDuration = 1000,
  excludedStatusCodes = []
}: {
  maxRetryAttempts?: number,
  scalingDuration?: number,
  excludedStatusCodes?: number[]
} = {}) => (attempts: Observable<any>) => {
    //FUNCTION IMPLEMENTATION
};
```

Comment: That's the default value, an empty object. You can convert it by removing the types, or let TSC do that for you.

Comment: I really don't  understand that syntax could you elaborate?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's break it down. Your function declaration basically has this structure:

```
export const myFunc = (<parameter>: <type> = <default>) => <implementation>;
```

The `<parameter>` portion of the declaration is a de-structured pattern which extracts the 3 specific properties and passes those property values to your function body. Each property is optional and is given a default value in the case it's value is `undefined` in the argument.

The `<type>` portion simply declares what type of argument is expected, in this case an object that contains three properties, all of which may be optional.

The `<default>` portion indicates what value will be substituted for this parameter if the argument is `undefined` or if none is provided. This allows you to call your function with no arguments at all, i.e. all of the following are equivalent:

```
genericRetryStrategy({ maxRetryAttempts: 3, scalingDuration: 1000, excludedStatusCodes: [] });
genericRetryStrategy({});  // use default property values
genericRetryStrategy();    // use default parameter value
```

Hopefully that clears up the syntax. To convert this to es7, all you have to do is get rid of the `<type>` portion of the declaration, like so:

```
export const genericRetryStrategy = ({
  maxRetryAttempts = 3,
  scalingDuration = 1000,
  excludedStatusCodes = []
} = {}) => (attempts) => {
    //FUNCTION IMPLEMENTATION
};
```